# C# parallel read access to List without copying

Tags: c#, .net, parallel-processing

Consider the following example:

```
class Example
{
    private readonly List<string> _list = new List<string>();
    private readonly object _lock = new object();

    public IReadOnlyList<string> Contents
    {
        get
        {
            lock (_lock)
            {
                return new List<string>(_list);
            }
        }
    }

    public void ModifyOperation(string example)
    {
        lock (_lock)
        {
            // ...
            _list.Add(example);
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

How could parallel read access to the `Contents` List be achieved without copying the whole List? In C# there are concurrent [`Collections`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997305(v=vs.110).aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), but there is no thread safe List. In Java there is something like the [`CopyOnWriteArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html).

Comment: How about [`ImmutableList<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn467185(v=vs.111).aspx) from `System.Collections.Immutable` package

Comment: What about blocking collection? (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: As long as you allow `ModifyOperation()` to be called while other code (possibly another thread) has access to the object returned from `Contents` then it will not be threadsafe if you return the underlying `List<T>` without making a copy (as you already do)

Comment: Is the `BlockingCollection<T>` thread safe to iterate?

Comment: `BlockingCollection` is thread safe to iterate if you use `BlockingCollection.GetConsumingEnumerable()`

Comment: @MatthewWatson Doesn't the `BlockingCollection.GetConsumingEnumerable()` empty the list while iterating? At least that is what I got from the documentation.

Comment: The alternative is to make a copy of the list on each "modify operation". This is what immutable collections do, although `ImmutableList<T>` is a bit more efficient than simply copying the entire list each time.

Comment: @IvanStoev `ImmutableList<T>` could indeed be an option. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, enumerating the item returned from GetConsumingEnumerable() does remove items from the collection.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In my opinion the [`ImmutableList<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn467185(v=vs.111).aspx) class from [System.Collections.Immutable](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Collections.Immutable/) package is perfect for such scenario. It implements `IReadOnlyList<T>`, and since it's immutable, i.e. never modified, you can directly return it from the read accessor. The only synchronization needed will be between the modifying operations:

```
class Example
{
    private ImmutableList<string> _list = ImmutableList<string>.Empty;
    private readonly object _lock = new object();

    public IReadOnlyList<string> Contents => _list;

    public void ModifyOperation(string example)
    {
        lock (_lock)
        {
            // ...
            _list = _list.Add(example);
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Lock-free suggestion...

```
class Example
{
    private ImmutableList<String> _list = ImmutableList<String>.Empty;

    public IReadOnlyList<String> Contents { get { return _list; } }

    public void ModifyOperation(String example)
    {
        ImmutableList<String> original;
        ImmutableList<String> afterChange;
        do
        {
            original = _list;
            afterChange = _list.Add(example);
        }
        while (Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref _list, afterChange, original) != original);
    }
}
```

Comment: Very nice. Thanks!